# Setup Elmah with MySQL?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I have run the Elmah nuget package, copied the `mysql.data.dll` to the bin folder and run the mySQL script in the database but where do I state the address and login to the database?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already installed Elmah and created the tables in your database all your should need to do now is make sure the tables have the correct permissions then edit the connection string for Elmah in your web.config to include the username and password for whatever account you'll access the DB from the same as any other connection string but using the MysqlClient

In your web.config you should have something similar to:

```
<elmah>
   <errorLog type="Elmah.MySqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.MySql" />
   <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
</elmah>
```

And also elsewhere in the connection strings bit something along the lines of:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Elmah.MySql" connectionString="[STUFF HERE];User ID=[WHATEVER];Password=[WHATEVER];" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the connection string. By running Install-Package elmah.mysql it was added. Could the connectionString be a ODBC or do it have to be a mySQL connector string?

Comment: It does not have to be mySQL at all.  Elmah supports a variety of different things.  Just make sure to have the appropriate log type and connection string for it.

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/   should be the full list

Comment: Yes I know but in this case I need to use the existing mySQL and have some trubbel with it. It says : SELECT command denied to user X for table 'proc'

Comment: You likely don't have the right permissions for whatever account is executing the command.  See what rights you have to the tables for that user.